# Do Moderators have an internal hierarchy?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Is there an authoritative figure to help lead the Moderators? Are some Mods given different duties to others? Or is *every* Mod given the exact same powers/privileges not matter how (in)experienced (s)he may be?

Comment: @Payeli Lol no, no (well definitely not yet, I'm nowhere near that standard, yet). I've just been reading up a lot about how exactly the Mod system works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> is every Mod given the exact same powers/privileges not matter how (in)experienced (s)he may be?

Yes. There are no "tiered" moderation levels. Moderators have moderator only chat rooms that allow them to discuss and learn from each other.

Most moderation actions are reversible, so even if a new (or existing) moderator makes a mistake, this is not an issue.

If a moderator start abusing their powers and don't stop the abuse even after being spoken to, they may end up being removed.

The "authoritative figure to help lead the Moderators" is the Community Management team - this is the group that moderators turn to for help.

Comment: Interesting, so are the Mod chat room(s?) similar to the normal chat rooms? And which actions aren't reversible?

Comment: @Sam - yes there are mod only chat rooms. Which actions? Destroying a user. Some account merges are very difficult to unmerge. But pretty much anything else can be reversed (many things by the community).